# Could i run docker in a docker Container Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker

The container is Ubuntu 14.04 64bits.
I installed docker in it reference https://docs.docker.com/v1.1/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-trusty-1404-lts-64-bit. When I run service docker start, it responded **mount: permission denied**.Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the instructions for the *de facto* standard Docker-in-Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jpetazzo/dind/), you need to run your original Docker container with the `--privileged` flag so that it can run Docker inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker ubuntu:14.04 docker images
```

This line shows you run docker command inside container. You must to share via -v the docker deamon and the socket file.

Other way if you need run this docker comands with other user than root is create other image inheriting FROM ubuntu and adding required user to docker group of the host.

[look at this](http://container-solutions.com/2015/03/continuous-delivery-with-docker-on-mesos-in-less-than-a-minute/)